# Redirecting Rails non www to www without disrupting user sessions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

Ok, so I want to redirect all non www domain requests to www.mydomain.com simply for Google/search engine consistency (I know all about canonical tags/google webmaster tools, let's ignore that)

I know the standard way to do this through Nginx (or htaccess for Apache).

However, the thing is this will probably disrupt user sessions right? For instance, if someone logged in through domain.com, their cookies will only be valid for domain.com, NOT www.domain.com, so by redirecting I'd make all users have to log in again.

Is there a way to make the redirect w/o disrupting user sessions?

Perhaps I can do something where I check for cookies? If it doesn't exist, then do the redirect. If it does, then don't redirect.

```
def index #controller method for requests from domain.com or www.domain.com
   @user = @requestManager.authorizedUser(cookies, params, logger) //check for cookies

   #if no cookies (Google bot or new visitor) 
   #and request is from domain.com, redirect to www.domain.com

   if(@user == nil and request.host =~ /^domain.com/)
            logger.info("Redirecting")
            redirect_to "http://www.domain.com", :status => 301
            return
    end
end
```

Would this work in redirecting non www to www.domain.com, and not disrupting current user sessions?

Comment: If you redirect people the instance they visit www.example.com to example.com, then they'll always be logged in to example.com.

Comment: @JesseWolgamott but I want the reverse...

Comment: the reverse is also true

Comment: @JesseWolgamott So if someone has cookies for example.com and I redirect to www.example.com, they won't need to relogin at all?

Comment: Are you worried about existing users once you go live with this change?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly my only worry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a cookie's domain hasn't been explicitly set it will be restricted to the hostname of the site where it was set.

If your users have long-term sessions that you really value, then this might achieve your goal:

1. modify your site to set domains wtih all cookies.
2. use firebug to check that the cookie is re-issued with the new domain when a user visits the site
3. wait a while until at least most of your users have visited the sit
4. enable the redirection

The users whose sessions will be lost are users who don't visit the site during the waiting period.

Comment: hmm... I hear you. what about the suggestion I made in my question? Would that give me what I want too?

Comment: Mostly.  You could do a combination of the two if you like.